# Basic server proxy implementation

Tags: python, server, proxy

The application gateway will get the requests and act as a proxy  between clients and servers. Clients will never directly communicate with the server. The  transferred file should have integrity and confidentiality as well. The proxy determines the session  keys. Assume that clients also know the public key of the application server.

```
import socket
import hashlib
import os
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

# Define the file server address and port
FILE_SERVER_ADDRESS = 'localhost'
FILE_SERVER_PORT = 12345

# Define the session key size
SESSION_KEY_SIZE = 16  # 128 bits

# Define the hash digest size
DIGEST_SIZE = 32  # 256 bits

# Define the username and password for authentication
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'password'

# Define the encryption algorithm and mode
ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM = 'AES'
ENCRYPTION_MODE = 'CBC'

# Define the hash algorithm
HASH_ALGORITHM = 'SHA-256'


def generate_session_key():
    # Generate a random session key
    return os.urandom(SESSION_KEY_SIZE)


def encrypt_message(message, session_key):
    # Encrypt the message using AES encryption in CBC mode
    cipher = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_CBC)
    iv = cipher.iv
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(message)
    return iv, ciphertext


def hash_message(message):
    # Hash the message using SHA-256
    hash_object = hashlib.sha256()
    hash_object.update(message)
    return hash_object.digest()


def authenticate_client(client_socket):
    # Receive the username and password from the client
    username = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    password = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()

    # Authenticate the user
    if username == USERNAME and password == PASSWORD:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def handle_client_request(client_socket):
    # Receive the client request
    request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()

    # Forward the request to the file server
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.connect((FILE_SERVER_ADDRESS, FILE_SERVER_PORT))
    server_socket.send(request.encode())

    # Receive the response from the file server
    response = server_socket.recv(1024)

    # Generate a session key for encryption
    session_key = generate_session_key()

    # Encrypt the response using AES
    iv, encrypted_response = encrypt_message(response, session_key)

    # Hash the encrypted response using SHA-256
    digest = hash_message(encrypted_response)

    # Send the encrypted response and digest to the client
    client_socket.send(session_key)
    client_socket.send(iv)
    client_socket.send(encrypted_response)
    client_socket.send(digest)

    # Close the sockets
    server_socket.close()
    client_socket.close()


def run_proxy():
    # Set up the server socket
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('localhost', 12346))
    server_socket.listen(5)

    # Accept client connections
    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()

        # Authenticate the client
        if authenticate_client(client_socket):
            # Handle the client request
            handle_client_request(client_socket)
        else:
            # Reject the connection
            client_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_proxy()
```

which parts should i modify for working application?